# How to have a changing name as Key and it's value as Count in select

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm doing a final select query, and I've noticed that it would be easier for my data if I could do something like:

```
var finalQuery = selectQuery
     .GroupBy(x => x.ProductName)
     .Select(c => new
     {          
     c.Key = c.Count()
     }).ToList();
```

Therefore, I want the returned data to be something like:

```
[{
"Clothes" : 5,
"Shoes" : 7,
"Laptop" : 10
}]
```

My current query is:

```
var finalQuery = selectQuery
     .GroupBy(x => x.ProductName)
     .Select(c => new
     { 
     ProductName = c.Key         
     ProductCount = c.Count()
     }).ToList();
```

I thought something like `c.Key.ToString()` would do the trick, but it doesn't work. I'm guessing the "Key" must be a set value to work, and it can't necessarily be dynamically changed?

Comment: `.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Count())` is what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that Yeldar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
var finalQuery = selectQuery.GroupBy(p => p.ProductName).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should customize the string using your own code, or you can use an external library as NewtonSoft.Json.
Below is a sample code that does the trick for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product("a", "Clothes"),
            new Product("b", "Shoes"),
            new Product("c", "Clothes"),
            new Product("d", "Clothes"),
            new Product("e", "Shoes"),
            new Product("f", "Shoes"),
            new Product("g", "Laptop"),
            new Product("h", "Laptop"),
            new Product("h", "Shoes"),
        };
        var result = products
            .GroupBy(p => p.Type)
            .Select(
                group => new 
                ProductCount(group.Key, group.Count())
                // You can use also an object as the commented code below
                //{
                //  Type = group.Key,
                //  Count = group.Count()
                //}
            )
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(ProductCount.ToFormatedString(result));
    }
    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Product(string name, string type)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
        }
    }
    class ProductCount
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public ProductCount(string type, int count)
        {
            this.Type = type;
            this.Count = count;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"\"{this.Type}\" : {this.Count}";
        }

        public static string ToFormatedString(IEnumerable<ProductCount> products) // if you need a more generic method, u can make this an extension method and use Reflection
                                                                                  // Or u can use a nuget package that formats objects to json (e.g: Newtonsoft is a good library)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("[{");
            foreach (var item in products)
                sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("}]");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```